# Dynamically creating an instance of a class

Tags: java

In the following, what I want to happen is that **w.someMethod()** returns an instance of **SomeSubClass**. Unfortunately it does not work. I believe the code will explain it better than I can.

```
public abstract class SomeSuperClass {
    public SomeSuperClass(int x) {
        // do nothing
    }
    public SomeSuperClass someMethod() {
        //this line
        return (new Class()).getDeclaredConstructor(getClass()).newInstance(1));
        //this line
    }
}

public class SomeSubClass extends SomeSuperCLass {
    public SomeSubClass(int x) {
        super(x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeSubClass w = new SomeSubClass(3);
    SomeSubClass q = w.someMethod();
}
```

Here is my return

```
SomeSuperClass.java:7: error: Class() has private access in Class
    return (new Class()).getDeclaredConstructor(getClass()).newInstance(1);
            ^
SomeSuperClass.java:7: error: incompatible types
    return (new Class()).getDeclaredConstructor(getClass()).newInstance(1);
                                                                       ^
required: SomeSuperClass
found:    Object
Main.java:4: error: incompatible types
    SomeSubClass q = w.someMethod();
```

To further clarify, the following code would do what I want:

```
public abstract class SomeSuperClass {
    public SomeSuperClass(int x) {
        // do nothing
    }
    public abstract SomeSuperClass someMethod();
}

public class SomeSubClass extends SomeSuperCLass {
    public SomeSubClass(int x) {
        super(x);
    }
    public SomeSuperClass someMethod() {
        return new SomeSubClass(1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeSubClass w = new SomeSubClass(3);
    SomeSubClass q = w.someMethod();
}
```

But I would like the **someMethod** to be in the class **SomeSuperClass**

Comment: What problems/errors are you encountering? If you are encountering any compiler error messages or any exception stacktraces, please post them here with your question. If you're encountering any program behavior problems, please describe them.

Comment: Specifically here, I am receiving that Class() has private access. If instead I make a call as Class.getDeclardedConstructor(...)..., I am then making a static call from a non-static context.

Answer (score 3):

`new Class` is not the proper way to obtain the class object. Instead the proper way is to use the method `getClass()`

```
return getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class).newInstance(1);
```

But you don't need to use reflection to create an object like the one you already have. Instead you can override the method `someMethod` the way JoeC suggest you.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the someMEthod() in your child class?

```
public class SomeSubClass extends SomeSuperCLass {
    public SomeSubClass(int x) {
        super(x);
    }
    public SomeSuperClass someMethod(){
        return new SomeSubClass(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do this, but if I had many classes that extend **SomeSuperClass*, I would like to avoid overriding **someMethod()** in every subclass.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is for this method to return a new instance of whatever class it is called on, using a constructor that takes an `int`, then you should do:

```
return getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class).newInstance(1);
```

But it's not clear why you wouldn't just override the method to explicitly instantiate the subclass in each subclass, as JoeC suggests.

Comment: Thank you, you and Cyrille Ka provided exactly what I was looking for.